# How to get kernel's console output in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to use `tf.Print` in `Colab`.

Below is the sample code:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()

tensor = tf.range(10)

tf.print("tensors:", tensor, {2: tensor * 2}, output_stream=sys.stdout)
```

How ever I cannot see the output, probably because the output goes to the notebook kernel's console output, not in the notebook cell output.

So how do I see the `colab` kernels console output?? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Select 'View runtime logs' from the Runtime menu.

Repeating your example:

[image]